# Obtain specific value using *ngFor in angular5

Tags: angular

The json response which I obtain is of the format:

0: { type: "bt", ItemName: " tab1"}

1: { type: "st", ItemName: " tab2 "}

This response I am storing in data2 and then printing the data as shown in code below:

```
<div class="form-group" >
<label>Item Name</label>
<select class="custom-select">
<option *ngFor="let data of data2; let i = index;" value = {{i}} >
                                                    {{data.ItemName}}
</option>
</select>
</div>
```

This is fetching all the values of ItemName from data2.

But I want to check the value of type in data2 and then print specific ItemName. 
So, if I select type as "st" then I only want all the ItemNames belonging to this type to be provided in dropdown.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a `<ng-container>`, store your selected value in a variable (let's say `myType='bt'`) and use `*ngIf` in your `<option>` tags:

```
<select class="custom-select">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let data of data2; let i = index;"> 
     <option value={{i}} *ngIf="data.type===myType">                                                    
       {{data.ItemName}}
     </option>
  </ng-container>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, you need to do both `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` operations, but we can't use them on the same element.

From [DOCS](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#one-structural-directive-per-host-element):

> You may apply only one structural directive to an element

But you can create an additional `<ng-container>...</ng-container>` element, something like this:

```
<select class="custom-select">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let data of data2; let i = index;">
    <option *ngIf="data.type === selectedType">
      {{data.ItemName}}
    </option>
  </ng-container>
</select>
```

And if you store the target type to the `selectedType` class property, it should work: `*ngIf="data.type === selectedType"` will filter and show only elements with specified type.

Here is a [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-vqsfdj?file=src/app/app.component.html).